How do you get printing info from a printer using C#?
I am making a C# Winforms application where my application needs to display information about pages that have been printed on a physical printing machine. It needs to get and display things like the number of pages printed, if they printed successfully, if they were black and white or color, and so on. I have never worked with code for printers before and I'm a beginner with C# so please be as specific as possible when explaining.
I haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start to be honest and I can't quite find info on the internet that is specific to my problem.

Sidenote. You can't get info from the Printer (you might but just for specific printers that have a proprietary API for that) You can get info from the Printer Driver. We don't know what you mean with "printed successfully" concretely. If you want somewhat guaranteed feedback if a correct printout is in the printers output tray it might not be sufficient to get info from the printer driver.  You should remove the "information-retrieval" tag its unhelpful here. And "Winforms" presumably irrelevant.
